# How to conveniently find local HTML documentation?

Tags: package-management, documentation, html

There are many doc packages in the repositories which provide documentation in HTML.

Is there an easy way to find locally installed HTML documentation, like `info` or `man`?

I guess I should clarify this a little.

The question is not about opening an HTML file. There are plenty of browsers out there and they do it pretty well.
The question is about working with the whole farm of documentation files on my computer, HTML docs in particular.

Among `/usr/share/doc/*` there are man pages, info files, some plain text files and a bunch of HTML files.

To look up information in man pages we use `man` utility, or `info` -- it looks through man too. But the situation with HTML docs is like if you had man pages on your computer but no `man` utility!

So, since there are HTML docs, there also could be a tool to work with them (to search for the documentation you need etc <-- and would be nice to have fuzzy search for that). Does such a tool exist?

Comment: What package have you used to generate the html documentation?

Comment: I do not generate html documentation -- I install it from ubuntu repository. The html is created with different tools: I believe GNU has some `info2html` tool, pythoners often use `Sphinx`.

Comment: I've asked [the same question on unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92839/is-there-html-documentation-browser-like-info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools to browse local documentation are `dhelp`, `dwww` and some more (`yelp` in Gnome). You can find more of them in [the wiki of the `doc-base` package](https://wiki.debian.org/doc-base).

`doc-base` registers documentation on the computer and all those programs are clients of this information.

Also, you can always navigate your broweser to: file:///usr/share/doc/ or any other directory and view html files from there. This way you avoid hassle with opening browser each time.

Comment: cool! it completely fell out of my head %) Though it would be nice to have something better: there is all kind of stuff in /usr/share/doc..

Comment: So, apparently, [debianers know their packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92839/is-there-html-documentation-finder-searcher-like-info-utility-for-info-files/92902?noredirect=1#92902)

Answer (score 1):

you can view the local .html with any browser.

Comment: yeah, but I need to know where the file is stored. I can look that up with `synaptic`'s search, or find it with `find`. But maybe there is a better way to do so? Like `man` or `info` do with man-pages and info-files. There could be a root html-file with links to all the rest of the html documentation on the machine, or something alike.

Comment: my guess would be /usrshare/doc/ or similar

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, **no**. You need to manually search using `*.html | grep "what you want"`. The `man` and `info` utilities have their own databases maintained which is not the case of HTML documents.